# Question about proving intersection of two transitive relation is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Suppose $R,S$ are transitive relations over $A$, prove that $R\cap S$ is transitive.

Let $x,y,z\in A$, since $R,S$ are transitive then $$(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\in R \wedge S\Rightarrow (x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\in R \cap S$$
So $R\cap S$ is transitive.

My question is, why this isn't the right approach?

Comment: Are you writing what you want to write? What is $R\land S$?

Comment: @GitGud um it's short for $(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\in R$ and $(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\in S$

Comment: OK. Recall the definition of a relation $T$ (on a set $A$) being transitive: $\forall x,y,z\in A(((x,y)\in T\land (y,z)\in T)\implies (x,z)\in T)$. Let $T=R\cap S$ and realise that what you're doing doesn't look like this.

Comment: @GitGud I can't suppose that $R,S$ already have those pairs $(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)$?

Comment: You can in the sense that it doesn't yield a contradiction, what you wrote in your question is actually true, but it doesn't prove that $R\cap S$ is transitive. To prove it, you need to prove what I wrote in my comment above.

Comment: @GitGud so having those pairs in a relation doesn't prove that it's transitive. What you wrote feels a little like we're supposing what we want to prove...

Comment: Related: [Intersect and Union of transitive relations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998299/intersect-and-union-of-transitive-relations). You can also find a proof at ProofWiki: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Transitive_Relations_is_Transitive

Comment: What I wrote is what needs to be proven, I'm not assuming it. You need to take $(x,y),(y,z)\in R\cap S$ and prove that $(x,z)\in R\cap S$.

Comment: @GitGud I think that your comments basically answer the question. (Which was *Why this is not correct?* OP can found answers to: *How to show this?* in the links mentioned above.) If you made an answer summarizing your comments, I would definitely upvote it. (Since I appreciate your effort to explain to the OP what is wrong with their alleged proof.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks, did so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP clarified that $(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\in R \wedge S$ is an abbreviation of $(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\in R\land (x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\in S$.

Let $x,y,z\in A$.

While $(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\in R \wedge S\Rightarrow (x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\in R \cap S$ is actually true, it doesn't prove that $R\cap S$ is transitive.

Recall that, by definition, a relation $T$ on $A$ is transitive if, and only if,

$$\forall x,y,z\in A(((x,y)\in T\land (y,z)\in T)\implies (x,z)\in T).$$

This doesn't look what you've written.

You want to prove that $((x,y)\in R\cap S\land (y,z)\in R\cap S)\implies (x,z)\in R\cap S$. As usual, assume the antecedent and try to get the consequent.