# The intersection of two transitive binary relations is transitive.

Tags: relations, self-learning

If the binary relations T and S are both transitive, then the intersection of these binary relations ( the binary relation $T \cap S$ is transitive.

My proof is as follows:

Let $\{ (x,y), (y,z)\} \in T$ and $\{ (x,y), (y,z)\} \in S$

Since T is transitive, $\{ (x,z)\} \in T$ as well.

Since S is transitive, $\{ (x,z)\} \in S$ as well.

So, $\{ (x,y), (y,z), (x,z)\} \in T$ and $\{ (x,y), (y,z), (x,z)\} \in S$

By definition of intersection

$T\cap S=\{ (x,y), (y,z), (x,z)\}$

That is, $T\cap S$ is also transitive.

Is this proof sufficient to show this statement?

Or how can improve my proof?

Thank you.

Comment: Your argument contains the right ideas. You may wish to change the way it's presented some (there are issues about $\in$ vs $\subseteq$ because of the many set braces, and the equality at the end is definitely not guaranteed). But more to the point: the logic of your argument may be clearer if you start with something like "let $(x, y), (y, z) \in T \cap S$" and from there proceed.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998299/intersect-and-union-of-transitive-relations)

Comment: Thank you so much @prets

Comment: Thank you so much  @Riccardo